# Natural order by integer in part of an array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array that containts these values:

> > Dancelesson 4 years
> >
> > Dancelesson 5 years
> >
> > Dancelesson 6 years
> >
> > Dancelesson 2-3 years

Above is sorted by ascending order, but I want 2-3 years to be first (because 2 is before 4 years). Is there a function to achieve this? (I've tried natsort, natsort, natcasesort  etc)

or would I have to create one myself for this purpose? (I guess I could cast the strings in the array to ints and then order them!?)

Comment: What's the code for the array? `array('Dancelesson 4 years', '...', ...)`?

Comment: @MarkM - why does that matter? I just want to sort an array in a specific way.

Comment: Have you tried `sort`? It should give desired result for your example

Comment: @hindmost - yes I've tried that as well. The thing is that (I guess) the sort algorithm sorts the string based that 2-3 are larger then 6 (or 5 or 4).

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld Nevermind it probably doesn't. Just verifying that the elements are stored as strings the way you have it written.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I can't understand what you need - ascending or descending order?

Comment: @MarkM - yes it's purely strings in the array.

Comment: @hindmost - I want the array to be sorted in ascending order, BUT sort(), natsort() etc doesn't sort my array as I wished to. I want it be sorted like this: Dancelession 2-3 years, Dancelession 4 years, Dancelession 5 years and Dancelession 6 years.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld `sort()` works fine: http://ideone.com/HukKnO

Comment: then your best best would be using usort and using your own custom sorting algorithm

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks !!! Nevermind. Forgive me for my stupidity. Of course it works fine. The issue was the ACTUAL array wasn't dancelession 2-3 BUT  dancelession2 (not the same course). LOL. Forgive me for wasting your time.